# Ignited Datatables - issue with links in add_column

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I'm using Ignited Datatables library and in my script I'm using the add_column function to set some edit and delete buttons. This is my script

```
$this->datatables->select('posts.id, posts.title')
        ->select('DATE_FORMAT(`date_published`, \'%d-%m-%Y\') AS `date_published`', false)
        ->select('posts_categories.title as category')
        ->from('posts')
        ->join('posts_categories', 'posts.category_id = posts_categories.id', 'left')
        ->unset_column('id')
        ->add_column('Actions', btn_edit('admin/posts/edit/$1') . ' ' . btn_delete('admin/posts/delete/$1'), 'id');
        return $this->datatables->generate();
```

The problem is that the post id doesn't pass in the url of the buttons, instead I get this: `admin/posts/edit/id`, where it should be `admin/posts/edit/1` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I 've found the solution to the problem.

In select() statement I did this and worked properly:

```
$this->datatables->select('posts.id AS pid, posts.title')
```

It seems that there was a conflict in the query in the primary keys of both tables, beacause I have set both as `id` (`posts.id` and `posts_categories.id`).

So back in the query when I set posts.id AS pid as an alias, this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply call database field name in code like

```
$this->datatables->select('posts.id as id, posts.title')
        ->select('DATE_FORMAT(`date_published`, \'%d-%m-%Y\') AS `date_published`', false)
        ->select('posts_categories.title as category')
        ->from('posts')
        ->join('posts_categories', 'posts.category_id = posts_categories.id', 'left')
        ->unset_column('id')
        ->add_column('Actions', btn_edit('admin/posts/edit/$1') . ' ' . btn_delete('admin/posts/delete/$1'), 'id');
        return $this->datatables->generate();
```

you were just missing to call **posts.id as id**. What the name you pass as a variable, you need to select same variable name in select command

Answer (score 0):

When wrapping variables to get their values, you have to use double quotes. So here should be:

```
->add_column('Actions', btn_edit("admin/posts/edit/$1") . ' ' . btn_delete("admin/posts/delete/$1"), 'id');
```

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: No it doesn't seem to work.. I have notice this, when I needed JOIN the post categories.. Before that (or if I remove the JOIN and the select category from the query) it was working absolutely fine and with single quotes too

Comment: Strange. Even on Datatables documentation double quotes are used for such example.

Comment: The problem appears with the JOIN statement only. If I remove this the links work properly

Comment: @Lykos, try to use `'posts.id'` instead of `'id'`

Comment: I tried it but didn't work neither, however I have found the solution. I'm gonna post it as an answer just in case anyone else has/had the same problem.